# Add custom view as subview on UIActionSheet in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a custom view and want to add in `UIActionSheet` as subview but in iPhone successfully added but when I try to add in iPad they show successfully but not show on the actionsheet as subview rather show on the top of the screen. look ipad screen short

[image]

iphone screen short

[image]

Comment: We've always put a check in before putting up our custom action sheet, and program it differently for iPad.  They work so differently.

Comment: This is a misuse of `UIActionSheet`. It is not designed to have custom views added to it. Don't fight the API. Do not use standard UI components in ways they were not intended to be used. Instead, implement your own UI control that does what you need here (or find one on github or cocoacontrols).

Comment: try to Set the frame and bounds property of your action for iPad frame .

Comment: i already set the property of frame and bounds but doesn't difference

Comment: @rmaddy i implemented own UI controller but nothing happened.